# next.js fetch cause infinite api request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

this code is from next js documentation which you can also find in the below link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
when i fetched an api using this method it causes infinite api request.

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...')
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.
 
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}
 
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData()
 
  return <main></main>
}
```

we cannot use the useeffect because it is server component.

Answer (score 2):

`res.json()` is a promise that needs to be resolved. **Replace**

```
return res.json()
```

with

```
return await res.json()
```